# Mapping and iterating nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, iteration

I am not too familiar with python but have a working understanding of the basics. I believe that I need dictionaries, but what I am currently doing is not working and likely very ineffective time-wise.

**I am trying to create a cross matrix that links reviews between users** given: the list of reviewers, their individual reviews, metadata related to the reviews.

**NOTE** : This is written in Python 2.7.10 - I cannot use Python 3 because outdated systems this will be run on, yada yada.

### For initialization I have the following:

```
print '\nCompiling Review Maps... ';
LbidMap = {};
TbidMap = {};
for user in reviewer_idx :
    for review in data['Reviewer Reviews'][user] :
        reviewInfo = data['Review Information'][review];
        stars = float(reviewInfo['stars']);
        bid = reviewInfo['business_id'];

        # Initialize lists where necessary
        # !!!! I know this is probably not effective, but am unsure of
        #  a better method. Open to suggestions !!!!!
        if bid not in LbidMap:
            LbidMap[bid] = {};
            TbidMap[bid] = {};
        if stars not in LbidMap[bid] :
            LbidMap[bid][stars] = {};
        if user not in TbidMap[bid] :
            TbidMap[bid][user] = {};

        # Track information on ratings to each business
        LbidMap[bid][stars][user] = review;
        TbidMap[bid][user][review] = stars;
```

(where 'bid' is short for "Business ID", pos_list is an input given by user at runtime)

I then go on and try to create a mapping of users who gave a "positive" review to a business T who also gave business L a rating of X (e.g., 5 people rated business L 4/5 stars, how many of those people also gave a "positive" review to business T?)

### For mapping I have the following:

```
# Determine and map all users who rated business L as rL
#  and gave business T a positive rating
print '\nCross matching ratings across businesses';
cross_TrL = [];
for Tbid in TbidMap :
    for Lbid in LbidMap :
        # Ensure T and L aren't the same business
        if Tbid != Lbid :
            for stars in LbidMap[Lbid] :
                starSum = len(LbidMap[Lbid][stars]);
                posTbid = 0;
                for user in LbidMap[Lbid][stars] :
                    if user in TbidMap[Tbid] :
                        rid = LbidMap[Lbid][stars][user];
                        print 'Tbid:%s  Lbid:%s  user:%s  rid:%s'%(Tbid, Lbid, user, rid);
                        reviewRate = TbidMap[Tbid][user][rid];
                        # If true, then we have pos review for T from L
                        if reviewRate in pos_list :
                            posTbid += 1;
                numerator = posTbid + 1;
                denominator = starSum + 1;
                probability = float(numerator) / denominator;
```

I currently receive the following error (print out of current vars also provided):

```
Tbid:OlpyplEJ_c_hFxyand_Wxw  Lbid:W0eocyGliMbg8NScqERaiA  user:Neal_1EVupQKZKv3NsC2DA  rid:TAIDnnpBMR16BwZsap9uwA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_edge_testAdvProb.py", line 90, in <module>
    reviewRate = TbidMap[Tbid][user][rid];
KeyError: u'TAIDnnpBMR16BwZsap9uwA'
```

So, I know the KeyError is on what *should* be the rid (review ID) at that particular moment within TbidMap, however it seems to me that the Key was somehow not included within the first code block of initialization.

What am I doing wrong? Additionally, suggestions on how to improve clock cycles on the second code block is welcomed.

---

**EDIT**: I realized that I was trying to locate `rid` of Tbid using the `rid` from Lbid, however `rid` is unique to each review so you would not have a `Tbid.rid` == `Lbid.rid`.

Updated the second code block, as such:

```
cross_TrL = [];
for Tbid in TbidMap :
    for Lbid in LbidMap :
        # Ensure T and L aren't the same business
        if Tbid != Lbid :
            # Get numer of reviews at EACH STAR rate for L
            for stars in LbidMap[Lbid] :
                starSum = len(LbidMap[Lbid][stars]);
                posTbid = 0;
                # For each review check if user rated the Tbid
                for Lreview in LbidMap[Lbid][stars] :
                    user = LbidMap[Lbid][stars][Lreview];
                    if user in TbidMap[Tbid] :
                        # user rev'd Tbid, get their Trid 
                        #  and see if they gave Tbid a pos rev
                        for Trid in TbidMap[Tbid][user] :
                            # Currently this does not account for multiple reviews
                            #  given by the same person. Just want to get this 
                            #  working and then I'll minimize this
                            Tstar = TbidMap[Tbid][user][Trid];
                            print 'Tbid:%s  Lbid:%s  user:%s  Trid:%s'%(Tbid, Lbid, user, Trid);
                            if Tstar in pos_list :
                                posTbid += 1;
                numerator = posTbid + 1;
                denominator = starSum + 1;
                probability = float(numerator) / denominator;
                evaluation = {'Tbid':Tbid, 'Lbid':Lbid, 'star':stars, 'prob':probability}
                cross_TrL.append(evaluation);
```

Still slow, but I no longer receive the error.

Comment: Add code to explicitly test whether the `rid` is in the `TbidMap`. If it's not, then you know where the problem starts.

Comment: @martineau - its clear to me that `rid` is not in `TbidMap`, though it should be added on the line `TbidMap[bid][user][review] = stars;` (end of first code block). If the `rid` exists, as it does since it is iterated over, then I do not understand why it is not tied to the user sub-dict within TbidMap. I almost wonder if it is being written over? But I am not experienced enough with python to fully understand if that is the case.

Comment: Seems overly complicated, from how you describe your problem I think  some SQL with a few joins could give you the answers you want more easily.